# React Admin: useRecordContext() returns undefined in Show Page

Tags: typescript, react-admin

In a very simple RA app, I want to display an object called "card", using a [Show Page](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ShowTutorial.html). The fields, here `id` and `title`, are properly displayed.

However, **the `useRecordContext()` hook always returns undefined** (as well as `useShowContext()` and `useShowController()` which I've also tried, see code below)  - and I can't figure out why.

Here's what I have in the ShowPage

```js
// ./cards/CardShow.tsx
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useRecordContext, useShowContext, useShowController } from 'react-admin';
import { Show, SimpleShowLayout, TextField } from 'react-admin';

const CardShow = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    console.log(id);        // OK: displays the id
    
    const record = useRecordContext();
    console.log(record);    // ERROR: undefined
    
    const {isLoading, record:record2} = useShowContext();
    if(isLoading) {return null}
    console.log(record2);   // ERROR: null

    const { data } = useShowController();
    console.log(data);      // ERROR: undefined

    return (
        <Show>
            <SimpleShowLayout>
                {/* Displays correct data which 
                    proves somehow the record is fetched */}
                <TextField source="id" /> 
                <TextField source="title" />                
            </SimpleShowLayout>
        </Show>
    )
};
export default CardShow;
```

I have the feeling I'm missing something really simple but I can't figure out what... Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

OK, got it. In case anyone wonders, the `useRecordContext()` is only available *below* the Show component, so now the following code works fine:

```js
import { useRecordContext } from 'react-admin';
import { Show, SimpleShowLayout, TextField } from 'react-admin';

const MyLayout = () => {
    const record = useRecordContext();
    console.log(record); // works!
    return (
        <SimpleShowLayout>
            <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="title" />
        </SimpleShowLayout>
    )
}

const CardShow = (
    <Show>
        <MyLayout />
    </Show>
)
export default CardShow;
```

Comment: This answer assisted me after a lot of research, thanks!